# Entity Framework does not update column after changing value of column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6. When I update a column of the database using EF. The record will update without any problem, but after I change the value of the column in SQL Server using update query EF does not update column value and does not throw any exception.

```
CustomerMandate customerMandate = await DbContext.CustomerMandates.FirstOrDefaultAsync(mandate => mandate.Id == 1, cancellationToken); 
if (customerMandate != null)
{
    customerMandate.State = newState;
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);// not working
}

DbContext newContext = new DbContext();
CustomerMandate customerMandate1 = await newContext.CustomerMandates.FirstOrDefaultAsync(mandate => mandate.Id == 1, cancellationToken); 
if (customerMandate1 != null)
{
    customerMandate1.State = newState;
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);// working
}
```

in normal execute of application update is ok but when i change value in database using T-SQL DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() return false but when i create new Context and get record from DB and change it DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()  return true
Any ideas?

Comment: please share your code with us.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, when you use update statement using EF it works , and when you use TSQL update statement it doesn't?

Comment: How are you try updating record in TSQL? I mean if you are using break-point somewhere in code?

Comment: EF works with a cache related to the context. There are different ways to update the cache but the best way to work is to use Unit Of Work pattern (DIspose the Context as soon as possible).

Comment: yes @Valkyriee you are right

Comment: in normal execute of application update is ok but when i change value in database using T-SQL DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() return false but when i create new Context and get record from DB and change it DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()  return true

Comment: Why would the change tracker report changes if you run a t-SQL update statement? How would it be aware of that? Tell *exactly* what you do, **when, where, in which order**. You run C# code, and t-SQL code, but it's still not clear how you expect them to interact.

Comment: The ChangeTracker is there for explicitly **not** interacting with the Database. HasChanges() checks if the snapshot of the entries in the object tree is the same as in the context's DbSets. I don't think any entry in a newly created DbContext has changes, you'll have to set the values in code (instead of surpassing it via direct T-SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to simulate situation of concurrent access. If yes, then please put break point at line

```
if (customerMandate != null)
```

Now, modify value in database and move ahead from the break-point. You would expect exception at `SaveChangesAsync` call.

Another think you can check is modify `state` in table using TSQL in management studio and then very if you new state was available in `customerMandate` when you run your program next time.

We cannot see where `DbContext` is defined and used before using it in line#1 of shared code. I hope you have made sure that any pending items/actions pending on that `DbContext` were completed before starting another update query. If not then those can cause failure.

Comment: thanks for your answer i edit my code to explain better would you please view it again?

Comment: What do you mean by "working" and "not working"? Do you mean that if value is changed in DB using TSQL (via SSMS) still you don't get `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` OR do you mean that database is not updated? I think answer of this will make question clear.

Comment: A DbUpdateConcurrencyException will not occur if no statements are sent to the database. Also, it will not happen if the EntityState if Modified and the tuple is indeed there (which it has to be unless deleted prior to SaveChanges()). I don't quite see where you get that assumption from.